# Try to create multiple contacts programmatically with same firstname

Tags: android

I use following code for creating new contact programmatically.
This code create a new contact in contact list with given details, but if firstname of contact same and run this code from loop for creating multiple contacts having same firstname fields e.g. "Crashre1234" then it add all fields in the single contact multiple time(according to loop). I use the current system time with fields to create difference.
But no luck.
I don't understand what I miss.

```
                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                op_list.clear();
                long tti = System.currentTimeMillis();
                ///for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    try{

                        int backRefIndex = 0;
                        System.out.println("Array List: "+backRefIndex);
                        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());
                        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Crashre1234"+"\r")
                        .build());
                        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                        /*op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "ABCre12")
                        .build());*/
                        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, "Secret password"+tti)
                        .build());
                        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, 11+tti)
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                        .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "")
                        .build());
                        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                         .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                         .withValue(Email.DATA, "Test@11test.com12"+tti)
                         .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                         .build());
                        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;
                         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
                         .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                         .withValue(Email.DATA, "mobile@test12.com12"+tti)
                         .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                         .build());
                        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

                         ContentProviderResult[] result = activity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
                         Uri uri = result[0].uri;
                         System.out.println("URI: "+uri);
                         System.out.println("Thread finish");
                          }catch(OperationApplicationException exp){
                           exp.printStackTrace();
                          }catch(RemoteException exp){
                           exp.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: add your code with correct format. atleast copy and paste it here so that we can format.

Comment: Why did you post this twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412400/try-to-create-multiple-contacts-programmatically-with-same-firstname

Comment: When I edit this post and add code with correct format and click on "Save Edits" button then it send page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your oplist declaration and initialisation inside, the for block.

```
long tti = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    op_list.clear();
    try{

        int backRefIndex = 0;
        System.out.println("Array List: "+backRefIndex);
        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
        .build());
        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

        op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Crashre1234"+"\r")
        .build());
        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

        /*op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "ABCre12")
        .build());*/
        //backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS, "Secret password"+tti)
        .build());
        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, 11+tti)
        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
        .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "")
        .build());
        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
         .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(Email.DATA, "Test@11test.com12"+tti)
         .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
         .build());
        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;
         op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
         .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(Email.DATA, "mobile@test12.com12"+tti)
         .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
         .build());
        // backRefIndex = backRefIndex+1;

         ContentProviderResult[] result = activity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
         Uri uri = result[0].uri;
         System.out.println("URI: "+uri);
         System.out.println("Thread finish");
          }catch(OperationApplicationException exp){
           exp.printStackTrace();
          }catch(RemoteException exp){
           exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```